# KDE 5: KFileDialog is no longer showing recent locations or URLs

Tags: plasma5, kde5

I've been using Debian Stretch with KDE Plasma for years. Now I upgraded to Buster, with KDE Plasma 5.14.5.

When I want to save a file, e.g. a download, the kdialog window no longer shows previous save locations, except the very last one and other fixed locations (root, home and Desktop paths).

[image: the location bar doesn't keep more than one previous location]

I can see in several config files, like $HOME/.kde/share/config/okularrc:

```
[KFileDialog Settings]

Recent URLs[$e]=/incredible/,$HOME/cit/tesis/,/tmp/,$HOME/Documentos/,/hulk/coro
```

And also in kdialogrc and kdeglobals.

However for some reason, when I open the dialog in Okular, the recent URLs listed in those configuration files are not present.

In addition, in okularrc for instance, there is another section:

```
[Recent Dirs]
okular[$e]=file:///tmp/,file://$HOME/Documentos/,$HOME/
```

which neither seems to be used. It doesn't have any effect on the dialog.

This was very useful, any idea where can I configure, or what should I do to have this feature back?

Regards.